# Finding a article

Tags: reference-request, fractional-calculus

I am studying the fractional derivative and I have read this book *The H-functions of one and two variables with applications* of H.M Sirvastava, K.C Gupta and S. P Goyal.

Part of this book is an article referenced by this title. (Raina R.k and Koul C.L(1977a) *Fractional derivatives of the H-functions*. Jnanabha 7. 97-105).

But I did not find anything. Can anyone help me find this article??

Comment: I'm afraid you will not always be able to find an article online. While most authors tend to upload their work to open access platforms like arXiv or put it straight away at their personal websites, not everyone does. Especially, old research papers tend to not be easily available online. The best I can suggest is that you check with your university library or e-mail the authors. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do not have the emails of these two authors. How can I find my email?

Comment: This is all I've found (thank Google):
Sirvastava: http://www.math.uvic.ca/~harimsri/
Goyal: https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=Vh2Rbz4AAAAJ&hl=en

I hope you can e-mail them. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. But I wrote to Professor Sirvastava, but he did not answer. I did not find Mr. Goyal's email either. I want to read an article by Mr. Goyal with the title " integrals involving the products of the H-function of two variables"(Goyal S.P and Vasishta S.K (1975)) please help me. Thanks

Comment: I don’t know how to help you. These articles are quite hard to find. Check with your university library or a professor who can have a better knowledge of this area. Good luck!

Comment: Tanks. I  found one of the articles I was looking for on the researchgate site. I requested full text but did not respond. what should I do? This is the link to the article in the researchgate. 
 
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267072351_Integrals_involving_the_products_of_the_H-function_of_two_variables

Comment: Using freely available internet sites (which I use all the time, by the way), more information about one of the papers can be found using [MR Lookup](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mrlookup) (gave [this](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0442310)) AND [zbMATH](https://zbmath.org/) (gave [this](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1195.33174) about the paper, and [this](https://zbmath.org/serials/?q=se%3A00007116) about the journal's full name). **(continued)**

Comment: [Googling the journal's full title](https://www.google.com/search?q="Vijnana+Parishad+Anusandhan+Patrika") gave [this](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.493306), which is not the volume you want, but it does show that it might be possible to find it.

Comment: This link has Indian language. What do I do?